# Setting A record to any external IP

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a very basic question, but the answer seems to be hidden between all the step-by-step tutorials of setting up domains.

I have a domain hosted on service A (let's call it a.com). Name servers are set to ns1.a.com, ns2.a.com. Now in a.com control panel I just pointed the A record to IP of my Digital Ocean droplet and it seems to work without any setup on the DO side.

Is it true then that I can add an A record pointing to ANY public IP and make ANY website appear under my domain or is it rather that default DO droplet settings are more permissive than for a typical production site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can point it to any IP address, but.

- The actual server will have a PTR (reverse DNS) record that differs from your domain name. Some services will check this and show an error that PTR and domain name are different.
- Anything using domain based certificates will throw an error, because the domain name and the domain name in the certificate are different.
- Mail and Web servers will not respond, unless the domain name is set to be one of the domains that server is responsible for.
- Other servers often have similar measures.

Comment: Ok, but in my real life example, I just did that and it worked. So in plain terms it's the web server's duty to whitelist domains and a fresh LEMP Digital Ocean droplet just happens not to be configured in that respect so it just serves it's web root directory to anything pointing to it, right?

Comment: Yes, you have to set the domain names in the vhosts.

Comment: @konrad  Note that web servers have a default vhost that will answer all queries to domains not defined in any other vhost (in Apache, it's the first one defined). If you want to prevent this "attack", this default host should not show your real content, but either dummy content or an outright error page.

Answer (score 1):

The DNS job will solve the A resource record to the value you specified on control panel, or in the zone configuration file / database.

In a shared environment, DO (or *you-name-it*) infrastructure has the duty for example to return correct resource according to different domains pointed to the same IP address.